# Targeting SVG inside img tag?

Tags: html, css, svg

Sorry but I don't seem to understand this one, how can I add an SVG into an IMG tag and target it for things like :hover or maybe changing colours at different breakpoints?

**HTML**

```
<img src="static/img/partner-logo.svg" alt="" width="118" height="44" class="partner-logo logo">
```

**CSS**

```
.partner-logo:hover {
fill: red
}
```

Comment: This might be useful - http://css-tricks.com/svg-tabs-using-svg-shape-template/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible, the external content is not accessible.

Your need to embed the SVG markup itself into your HTML document.